# Extract content from wikipedia

Tags: php

I'm building a website with ever changing data, and I figure using the data from wikipedia would help update my site. However, after messing around with some stuff I created to pull this content I've run in to some issues.

There is a certain `<td>` that holds some information I need to select, but it doesn't have an ID or anything making it special.

**Here is the table row on the wikipedia page I need to select**

```
<tr class="">
<th scope="row" style="text-align:left; font-weight: normal"><b>Total</b></th>
<td class="" style="">36</td>
</tr>
```

I need to just extract the **36** from the `<td>`. Any ideas on going about this?

Also here is the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Diaz

Comment: [Have you tried anything yet?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Search for HTML parser

Comment: If you want to use content from WikiPedia, don’t scrape their web pages, but use their API instead. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Comment: @CBroe I didn't think of that, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use the API to scrape the wikitext as JSON. Do that by fetching this URL:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Nick_Diaz&prop=wikitext&format=json
```

Then, assuming the result is in `$data`, do this:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$data = $data['parse']['wikitext']['*'];
```

Now all the wikitext is in `$data`. It just so happens that the total is calculated from five fields:

- `mma_kowin` — Knockout
- `mma_subwin` — Submission
- `mma_decwin` — Decision
- `mma_dqwin` — Disqualification
- `mma_otherwin` — Other

You can parse these fields out pretty easily with a regular expression:

```
/^\s*\|\s*mma_([a-z]+)win\s*=\s*(\d*)/m
```

You'll want to find all matches of that regular expression in `$data`. The first group will be `ko`, `sub`, etc. The second match will be a string representation of the number or an empty string for zero. Then you'll want to add all of those numbers up, and bam, you've got it.

All together now:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Nick_Diaz&prop=wikitext&format=json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$data = $data['parse']['wikitext']['*'];

preg_match_all('/^\s*\|\s*mma_([a-z]+)win\s*=\s*(\d*)/m', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$wins = array();
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $wins[$match[1]] = (int)$match[2];
}

?>
<h1>Nick Diaz's Wins</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>Means</th><th>Wins</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Knockout</td><td><?php echo $wins['ko']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Submission</td><td><?php echo $wins['sub']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Decision</td><td><?php echo $wins['dec']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Disqualification</td><td><?php echo $wins['dq']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Other</td><td><?php echo $wins['other']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong><?php echo array_sum($wins); ?></strong></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey man, here is what I've got so far. 

`$data = http_get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Nick_Diaz&prop=wikitext&format=json");
  $data = json_decode($data);
  $data = $data['parse']['wikitext'];
  $result = preg_match("/^\s*\|\s*mma_([a-z]+)win\s*=\s*(\d*)/", $data);` I keep getting 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get() on line 100'

Comment: @ChristianPage: [`http_get`](http://www.php.net/http_get) is part of [`pecl_http`](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http), which [is not installed by default](http://www.php.net/http.install). You'll have to find some other way to fetch it. ([`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) works well when [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled; [`curl`](http://www.php.net/curl) is another, more explicit option.)

Comment: @ChristianPage: Also, I'd use single quotes rather than double quotes to quote the regular expression and [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) will match all them at once, which is more convenient than a bunch of separate [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) calls.

Comment: When I use `file_get_contents` I get this error instead 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

Comment: @ChristianPage: I forgot a parameter to `json_decode`. Replace `$data = json_decode($data);` with `$data = json_decode($data, true);`.

Comment: Still getting the same last error.

Comment: How can I pull the total fights row?

Comment: @ChristianPage: You can't pull it directly; that regular expression finds the number of each kind. Add all of those up to get the total.

Comment: I keep getting the value of 0.

Comment: @ChristianPage: I've edited my answer to include my working code.

Comment: Anyway to redo that regex to where it returns anything I need to select?

Comment: @ChristianPage: Yes. I suggest you learn regular expressions if you have not already done so. Then I would try to extract just the infobox from the rest of the wikitext. Then you can run an appropriate regular expression. For that page, you'll probably just need to make it select every little template parameter rather than just the `mma_*win` ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** methods to solve this.

1. Use wikipedia's API - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial
2. Use a HTML parser - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It really depends on method you select. Select a method and let me know if you have any issues.You can find tutorials for both methods without and issue.

## Note

According to my know using an API would be better rather than depending on the DOM structure since they tend to change quite frequently.

Comment: 1 looks like something I would like to use. How can I construct this?

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications